# Show the items when searched

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

I am made a listbox, save button and a search button, I also made an array so when the save button is pressed, the data were placed into the array, but I want to show it in the listbox when searched,
here is my code for search

```
foreach (Person per in Person.listperson)
            {
                if (textBox6.Text == per.lastname.ToString())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(per.lastname);
                }
            }
```

thanks :)

Comment: What is the question? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can databind ListBox with your list

```
private void Bind(List<Person> searchResults)
{
     //lb = your list box
     lb.DisplayMember = "lastname";
     lb.ValueMember = "id";
     lb.DataSource = searchResults;
}
```

and this will bind all items in your list to list box showing them :)

Also your search can be done by LINQ:

```
var results = Person.listperson.Where(x => x.lastname.ToString() == textBox6.Text).ToList();
Bind(results);
```

Hope it helps :)